# is Xanthosine Xanthine plus ribose?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm so confused. I used to think Xanthosine is Xanthine with a ribose instead of H but it appears to me as if it isn't. If you look at the picture in top-right of its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthine) you will see that the Imidazole is reversed from the picture in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthosine) also the picture in the bottom of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxanthine) page in additional images section is like the second one. I'm sorry if didn't use the right chemical terms! I'm no chemist. Also I while I was searching I saw different images for Adenine and Guanine where the Imidazole loop was reversed in some by reversed I mean like the position of NH and N was reversed with respect to the Benzene loop!

P.S. It would be great if you could also teach me the correct way to ask this question by means of the chemical terms I should use.

P.S.S I hope it is not a wikipedia problem!

Comment: All they’ve done is flip the picture…

Comment: Have you ever heard of [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/73323#section=Top)? It's a great resource for chemical structures as well as other information.

Comment: @canadianer no it is not. pay attention to the relative position of NH in Imidazole to the Os in the Benzene Ring.

Comment: @anongoodnurse according to PubChem the image at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthine is wrong. but is PubChem completely reliable?

Comment: They are the same. The purine imidazole can exist in two tautomeric forms.

Comment: @canadianer I understand that they are tautomers but I don't understand how they are the same! I think they are not the same bc altho the imidazole  is symmetric, the other ring is not. and since there are two bonds between them they can't turn so it matters so much don't you agree that they will look differently under an electron microscope?

Comment: 9H-xanthine (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=17712) is a tautomer of 7H-xanthine (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=CHEBI:48517)

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "same". Tautomers are often considered to be the same compound even though they are constitutional isomers.

Comment: On the question "Is PubChem/Wikipedia/etc completely reliable?" the answer is "not completely!". It is very hard to get all chemical data 100% correct, but there are efforts to cross-check and validate such data with experts...

Comment: @canadianer I was just imagining there were long carbon chains instead of hydrogen in imidazole and another chain in the other ring and then I thought the structure would vary so much because the angle between the carbon chains would be so different and thus different properties. But if you say tautomers are considered to be the same compounds then I suppose such things just don't happen often and the properties of tautomers are almost just the same. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two structures are [tautomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautomer) of one another:

[image]

Tautomers are often considered the same compound even though they are really constitutional isomers. Technically they are called [7H-xanthine](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=48517) and [9H-xanthine](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=17712), respectively (thanks to gilleain for the links).